# Only one class may appear in a supertype list

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-fragments, superclass

I am running into trouble with having two superclasses. When I am adding the MainActivity() I am recieving the error: Only one class may appear in a supertype list.

Any ideas on how I can work around this problem?

```
class ExaminationFragment : Fragment(),MainActivity()  {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_examination, container, false)
    }

}
```

Comment: You cannot inherit from two classes in Kotlin.

Comment: `Any ideas on how I can work around this problem?` yes, you need to review the basics and think about what you're doing, why would `ExaminationFragment` be an activity ? it doesn't make sense for fragments to inherit from activities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin you can inherit only one `class`, but multiple `interfaces`. In your case `Fragment` and `MainActivity` are classes, you can't inherit both of them. I guess you don't need to inherit `MainActivity` class by fragment class `ExaminationFragment`, inheriting `Fragment` class is enough for displaying a screen:

```
class ExaminationFragment : Fragment() { ... }
```

Please [see how to create Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create). In the provided example `ExampleFragment` is inherited from `Fragment` class, and doesn't inherit from any `Activity` class.